# (InternalError) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation in boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a series of files that are in JSON that need to be split into multiple files to reduce their size.  One issue is that the files are extracted using a third party tool and arrive as a JSON object on a single line.

I can use S3 select to process a small file (say around 300Mb uncompressed) but when I try and use a larger file - say 1Gb uncompressed (90Mb gzip compressed) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] EventStreamError: An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
```

The query that I am trying to run is:

```
select count(*) as rowcount from s3object[*][*] s
```

I can't run the query from the console because the file is larger than 128Mb but the code that is performing the operation is as follows:

```
def execute_select_query(bucket, key, query):
    """
    Runs a query against an object in S3.
    """
    if key.endswith("gz"):
        compression = "GZIP"
    else:
        compression = "NONE"
    LOGGER.info("Running query |%s| against s3://%s/%s", query, bucket, key)
    return S3_CLIENT.select_object_content(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key,
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression=query,
        InputSerialization={"JSON": {"Type": "DOCUMENT"}, "CompressionType": compression},
        OutputSerialization={'JSON': {}},
    )
```